# Paypal Express Checkout with Parallel Payments

Tags: php, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal

I am using Paypal ExpressCheckout method for my payments. I need to enhance my payment like paying multiple merchants using Express Checkout with Parallel Payments. And I have gone through the tutorial. When I submit, I am getting the error. My sent data is

```
&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
&RETURNURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.net%2Fpaypal_process.php
&CANCELURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.net%2Fcancel.php
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=SGD
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=50
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=50
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=email@mydomain.com.sg
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTREQUESTID=CART26488-PAYMENT0
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Depart San Jose Feb 12 at 12:10PM Arrive in Baltimore at 10:22PM
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=Flight 522
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=50
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=SJC Terminal 1. Flight time: 7 hours 12 minutes
```

Error :

```
Error : This account is not approved for the authorization service. To enable this service, contact PayPal customer service

Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2014%2d10%2d20T09%3a36%3a03Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 4a7ab68babd8b
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 109%2e0
    [BUILD] => 13443904
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 11623
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => This%20account%20is%20not%20approved%20for%20the%20authorization%20service%2e
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => This%20account%20is%20not%20approved%20for%20the%20authorization%20service%2e%20To%20enable%20this%20service%2c%20contact%20PayPal%20customer%20service
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

I have surfed through internet about this error. But I cannot find the one. Please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a surf from utter basics, I have found the answer. The PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION paramater value should be url encoded before sent.

```
"PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION='".urlencode("Sale")
```

Answer (score -1):

It is because the email address `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID` `email@mydomain.com.sg` is not confirmed.
Try to confirm the email address and execute the API call again.